# Is $ \operatorname{lin}(\mathcal{V}) $ the same as $ GL(n,\mathbb{C} )$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

In an introductory linear algebra course, the notation " $\in $ lin$(\mathcal{V}) $ " is frequently used to mean the set of linear operators over a previously defined vector space, and I'm wondering if  the notation " $ \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ " would be *loosely* equivalent?

Comment: Yes, if you add "invertible" and $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "the same". Assuming that $V$ has dimension $n$ (which you didn't even assume), to identify with matrices you need to fix a basis of $V$. Two different (non-proportional through a single scalar) bases yield different identifications.

Answer (score 1):

No. The set $GL(n,\Bbb C)$ is the set of all invertible $n\times n$ complex matrices. It can be seen as the set of all *invertible* linear maps from $\Bbb C^n$ into itself, but not as the set of *all* linear maps.